# how to moq simple add function that uses Unit of Work and Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

My test looks like this

```
        [Fact]
    public void SimpleAddTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var authorizationsToBeAdded = new List<PatientPayerAuthInfo>
        {
            new PatientPayerAuthInfo (),
            new PatientPayerAuthInfo  ()
        }.ToList();
        var persistentAuthorizations = new List<PatientPayerAuthInfo>
        {
            new PatientPayerAuthInfo {PatientPayerAuthInfoId = 1 },
            new PatientPayerAuthInfo  {PatientPayerAuthInfoId = 2 },
             new PatientPayerAuthInfo  {PatientPayerAuthInfoId = 3 },
             new PatientPayerAuthInfo  {PatientPayerAuthInfoId = 4 }
        }.AsQueryable();

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<PatientPayerAuthInfo>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<PatientPayerAuthInfo>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(persistentAuthorizations.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<PatientPayerAuthInfo>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(persistentAuthorizations.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<PatientPayerAuthInfo>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(persistentAuthorizations.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<PatientPayerAuthInfo>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(persistentAuthorizations.GetEnumerator());

        var mockedUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUOW<DBContext>>();     

        var service = new PatientPayerService(mockedUnitOfWork.Object);

        // Act
        var sut = service.AddPatientPayerAuthInfos(authorizationsToBeAdded);

        // Assert

    }
```

service layer function looks like this

```
        public void AddPatientPayerAuthInfos(IEnumerable<PatientPayerAuthInfo> patientPayerAuthInfos)
    {
        foreach (var patientPayerAuthInfo in patientPayerAuthInfos)
        {
            UOW.PatientPayerAuthInfos.Add(patientPayerAuthInfo);
        }
        UOW.SaveChanges();
    }
```

AND Repository implementation is

```
     public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);
        }
    }
```

which then has a commit method that calls EF's SaveChanges.

my question is how we can Setup mockedUnitOfWork using persistentAuthorizations so that when i add Two objects using authorizationsToBeAdded then the total count of persistentAuthorizations  becomes 6, which are 4 initially.

or correct me if i am on wrong track.

```
  public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
  {
    void Add(T entity);
   }

public interface IUOW<U> where U : DbContext, IDisposable
{        
    IRepository<PatientPayerAuthInfo> PatientPayerAuthInfos { get; }
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list as base for `persistentAuthorizations` like:

```
var data = new List<PatientPayerAuthInfo>
{
    new PatientPayerAuthInfo {PatientPayerAuthInfoId = 1 },
    new PatientPayerAuthInfo {PatientPayerAuthInfoId = 2 },
    new PatientPayerAuthInfo {PatientPayerAuthInfoId = 3 },
    new PatientPayerAuthInfo {PatientPayerAuthInfoId = 4 }
};
var persistentAuthorizations = data.AsQueryable();
```

Then you can setup `mockedUnitOfWork` like this:

```
var repositoy = new Mock<IRepository<PatientPayerAuthInfo>>();

// when adding data to the repository, add the item to 'data' 
repositoy.Setup(r => r.Add(It.IsAny<PatientPayerAuthInfo>()))
         .Callback(delegate(PatientPayerAuthInfo y)
                   {
                        data.Add(y);
                   });

// when accessing 'PatientPayerAuthInfos', use the repository mock
var mockedUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUOW<DBContext>>();
mockedUnitOfWork.SetupGet(x => x.PatientPayerAuthInfos).Returns(() => repositoy.Object);
```

Comment: when we are trying to setup property  PatientPayerAuthInfos  it is of type IRepository and we are setting it up with data. which is not working. 

other than that PatientPayerAuthInfos and all other such properties does not have any setters. 

    IRepository<PatientPayerAuthInfo> PatientPayerAuthInfos { get; }

Comment: So `IUOW` is derived from `IRepository`?